# Display downloaded data from database in tableview

Tags: mysql, json, swift, nsmutablearray

I created a database with PHPMyAdmin. Then I uploaded a php file to a web service to load the database. Now I have the url of the php file, which load the database.

This code works fine to load the database into the app:

```
func retrieveData() {
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: phpURL)!
    var data:NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
    json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as NSMutableArray

    for (var i:NSInteger = 0; i < json.count; i = i + 1) {
        newPlatz = json.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("Platz") as? NSString
        newVerein = json.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("Verein") as? NSString
        newPunkte = json.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("Punkte") as? NSString
        newDifferenz = json.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("Differenz") as? NSString
        newSpiele = json.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("Spiele") as? NSString

        var myBundesliga:Bundesliga = Bundesliga.alloc()
        myBundesliga.initWithBundesligaID(newPlatz, nVerein: newVerein, nSpiele: newSpiele, nDifferenz: newDifferenz, nPunkte: newPunkte)
        bundesligaArray = NSMutableArray.alloc()
        //bundesligaArray.addObject(myBundesliga)

        println("\(newPlatz!);\(newVerein!);\(newPunkte!);\(newDifferenz!);\(newSpiele!)")

    }


}
```

The output in the console:

```
1;FC Bayern München;17;13;7
2;TSG Hoffenheim;13;5;7
3;Bor. Moenchengladbach;13;5;7
4;Bayer 04 Leverkusen;12;2;7
5;1. FSV Mainz 05;11;4;7
```

and so on...

It works perfectly. But now i do not know how to display the data in my tableview. As you can see in the code above, the line code behind the two slashes do not work perfectly. Always when i run the app there is a 'Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1' error in this line:

```
bundesligaArray.addObject(myBundesliga)
```

I do not know why. Can somebody help me?

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't necessarily advise the `alloc`/`init` model for the `Bundesliga` object, either. (I'm actually a little surprised that that works.) I would use the standard Swift `init` methods and then instantiate it with `var myBundesliga = Bundesliga(platz: newPlatz, nVerein: newVerein, nSpiele: newSpiele, nDifferenz: newDifferenz, nPunkte: newPunkte)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you're instantiating your objects. You have:

```
bundesligaArray = NSMutableArray.alloc()
```

That should be:

```
bundesligaArray = NSMutableArray()
```

And, of course, you want to define that *before* your `for` loop, not inside it.

---

Or, if you wanted to use a Swift array, you'd define `bundesligaArray` as:

```
var bundesligaArray: [Bundesliga]?
```

And you'd instantiate it with

```
bundesligaArray = [Bundesliga]()
```

And you'd add objects to it with

```
bundesligaArray?.append(myBundesliga)
```